# Find the general solution of a linear system of ODEs, with non-constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is given, that the following system of ODEs has a non-trivial solution with a constant y axis

\begin{alignat*}{4}
   \frac{dx}{dt} = x-e^{-t}y \\
   \frac{dy}{dt} = 2e^tx-y \\ 
\end{alignat*}

Find the general solution of this system.

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Are you learning to solve it as a first-order system or possibly decouple into a single second-order equation instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply the top equation by $e^t$ and subtract this first equation from the second.  The result is
$$y'-e^tx' = xe^t.$$
$$y' = e^tx' + xe^t = \frac{d}{dt}(e^tx).$$

Thus,
$$y = e^tx + C_1.$$

Substitute into original first equation.

$$x' = x - e^{-t}(e^tx + C_1).$$
$$x' = x-x-C_1e^{-t} = -C_1e^{-t}.$$

You should be able to continue from here.  Solve for $x(t)$.  Then,
simply substitute to find $y(t)$.

You will find that $y$ constant is a special case.